# how to add numbering on each markers in Google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to ask you all about how to add number dynamically on each markers in Google Maps v3 with JavaScript. For example, the first marker is 1, the second one is 2, etc. In this case I have position data like this :

```
[
 new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000), 
 new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.0000, 9.0000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.0000, 9.0000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.5142, -0.0931),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.5142, -0.0931),
 new google.maps.LatLng(54.0000, -2.0000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.6000, -1.2500),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.7500, -1.2500)
];
```

But that data dynamically change. So for the first position lat/long I will give the number 1 on first marker, number 2 for the second marker, etc. And also i have use the icon each marker with this :

```
"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900"
```

Do I have to change the marker icon?
I really need your suggest or example code to fix the problem. Please help. Thank You very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your starred pin icon and add an unobtrusive label next to it. This label can say anything but I kept it to simply a number. It is the [MarkerWithLabel library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/examples/basic.html) ([download here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js))

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/21/

[image: pin with number]

You need to define a CSS for it too.

```
  .labels {
     color: blue;
     background-color: white;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 25px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
​
```

And replace your regular Marker with MarkerWithLabel:

```
for (var i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        map: map,
        position: point[i],
        icon: pinImage,
        shadow: pinShadow,
        labelContent: i,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(12, -5),
        labelClass: "labels"
    });
}
```

Including in the HTML file

```
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
      .labels {
        color: blue;
        background-color: white;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width: 25px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
      ...
```

Comment: very thank you for your help (again). so, I want to ask you about your answer. For markerwithlabel_packed.js, I've never known about that script. It's really difficult to understand, especially for newbie like me. But I try to learn about even it need long time to do. 
And for the CSS, do I need to make new file? or I just can add it into my JavaScript?? Very big thanks for you.

Comment: Yes, the markerwithlabel_packed is confusing, because it is meant to save bandwidth. What needs to be done is add the .labels to the style tag and the markerwithlabel included just like how the google maps API is included. If you want to be extra careful, download that file and include the local copy. Please see the end of my updated answer.

Comment: oh, @Lilina, I will try it soon. I now understand after I have seen your updated answer. For markerwithlabel, you include the library with the link like Google Maps API. If I save it in my local disk so what is the link would be like?? Is it like :
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:xampp/htdocs/semuabaru/markerwithlabel_packed.js"></script>

Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks Lilina ...

Comment: For local copies, it's best to use relative paths, I mean, just keep it in the same folder as your php file and write script type="text/javascript" src="markerwithlabel_packed.js" I am suggesting you save the file because once I saw the remote file get changed and my app broke.

Comment: I'll tell you then Lilina ... :)

Comment: It works Lilina. I'm so glad to try this. It's because of your help. VEry very big thanks for everything for you Lilina :)

Comment: I think I need your help anymore. Because you're always detail to explain to me and make me easy to understand. this is about the map [again]. I just want to add marker cluster for markers whic in the same lat/long. But I'm afraid that will influent my map which there are infowindow, the marker with label, and polyline. Would you mind to explain to me Lilina ??

Comment: And also I've posted my question. There is an answer but I still hard to understand and implement it. This is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974258/how-to-add-marker-cluster-in-google-maps-v3-for-the-same-lat-long-without-influe 
Thank You very much.

Comment: Okay how can I make the point array to be dynamic, i mean instead of hardcoding my lat/lngs , what if I get a set of lat/lngs from DB using ajax and then do this. its not working for me, because the maps load first and then the ajax call.. any solution?

Comment: @Faizan I recommend you open a new question. I forgot how to Javascript

Comment: For people using this, there are newer versions of the javascript, have a look at http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/

However, my code worked with v 1.1.5 and _not_ v 1.1.9. Take that how you will...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways. Changing the marker image is one, but requires you to make all those marker images. Another is to use the [StyledMarker library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/) which is part of the [Google Maps API Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries).

Comment: Mr. Chad, could you give some example?? I'm newbie so i don't know what to do with the StyledMarker library ...
Thank You

Comment: The StyledMarker library I linked has both documentation and examples such as this one: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/examples/simple.htm

Comment: So we just have the file of StyledMarker.js then we call the class in our map file, don't we?? 
Thank You