# how to add marker cluster in google maps v3 for the same lat/long without influenting another element?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I made traceroute map. And I have problem with some markers that should be in the same lat/long but only one marker show on the map. I read that there's a way to do. It is marker cluster. but I don't know how to add in javascript. Also I'm afraid if that would be influent another element of markers which I've add like custom marker with label, infowindow and polyline. 
here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900",
        new google.maps.Size (70, 83),
        new google.maps.Point (0,0),
        new google.maps.Point (10,34));
    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
        new google.maps.Size (89, 85),
        new google.maps.Point (0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point (12, 35));

    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.822591, 150.46875);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    <?php
    $posisi = array();
    $keterangan = array();
    foreach ($integer as $lokasi) {
    $query = "SELECT cl.locId, cl.country as country, cl.region as region, cl.city as city, cl.postalCode as postalCode, cl.latitude as latitude, cl.longitude as longitude, cl.metroCode as metroCode, cl.areaCode as areaCode
    FROM (SELECT locId as idcihuy FROM cityblocks WHERE $lokasi BETWEEN startIpNum AND endIpNum) cb, citylocation cl WHERE cb.idcihuy = cl.locId";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($location = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $posisi[]= 'new google.maps.LatLng(' . $location['latitude'] . ', ' . $location['longitude'] . ')';
    $keterangan[]= '"(' . $location['country'] . ',  ' . $location['region'] . ',  ' . $location['city'] . ')"';
    }
    }
    ?>
     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
     var point = [<?php echo implode(',', $posisi) ?>];
     var lokasi = [<?php echo implode(',', $keterangan) ?>];
     var icon = pinImage;
     for (var i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
     var html = "<b>" + lokasi[i] + "</b> <br/>" + point[i];
     var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        map: map,
        position: point[i],
        icon: pinImage,
        shadow: pinShadow,
        labelContent: i,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(12, -5),
        labelClass: "labels"
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    var jalur = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: point,
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2.25
    });
    jalur.setMap(map);
        }
        }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
    </script>
```

Also I give you the sample of positions which have the same lat/long :

```
[
 new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000), 
 new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.0000, 9.0000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.0000, 9.0000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.5142, -0.0931),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.5142, -0.0931),
 new google.maps.LatLng(54.0000, -2.0000),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.6000, -1.2500),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.7500, -1.2500)
];
```

I need the help to make the marker cluster for same lat/long but that would not influent another element like marker with label, infowindow and polyline. Please Help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) library.

> **MarkerClusterer for Google Maps v3**
>
> The library creates and manages per-zoom-level clusters for large
>   amounts of markers.

[Example](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/simple_example.html)

When you zoom in on a cluster you can see multiple markers in one location.

**EDIT:**

```
// GET AN EMPTY ARRAY
var markerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {

    // CODE AT THE BEGINNING OF LOOP

    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        // MARKER CONFIGS
    });
    markerArray.push(marker);

    // REST OF THE CODE IN LOOP
}

// TIME FOR ACTION
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);
```

Comment: Thank you @Salman for answer my question. But is there any other example to do?? because I'm newbie and a little hard to understand.

Comment: and do I need to define the CSS for it too ??

Comment: Check out this example for 100 markers on this page- http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html. As you can see it puts all the the markers in an array using a `for` loop. You already have a loop going so you need to make a slight modification to that.

Comment: From my script to custom marker with label I inserted the library file markerwithlabel_packed.js, then I call the function in my map file. Do I need to do like that?? Is it the way to do like I've posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958722/how-to-add-numbering-on-each-markers-in-google-maps-v3 ?? Thank You Salman.

Comment: That is OK I guess. Just store those markers in an array then call the cluster library function after the loop.

Comment: yes thank you for your explanation. It works but when I zoom the marker with label and the infowindows didn't show. I've tried like your edit. Any other thing I should do Salman?

Comment: I'm sorry for just reply your answer. because I have the problem of my internet connection. I've tried to check the error. but there's nothing error. Any something I have to add? Thank You.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because it does not work. It's a copy from the Google Docs which are incorrect. The problem is that `MarkerCluster()` is not defined. It's supposed to extend `google.maps.OverlayView()`